'points' do not add up but are simply overwritten
'points' do not add up but are simply overwritten, for example, if I have an object with 10 points and an object with 50 points, then they simply reset the result and it turns out that they raised 10 points, received 10 points, picked up another and still 10 points.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class SellItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject itemToSell;
    public int scoreValue = 10; // Значение очков для этого предмета
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText; 
    private int score = 0;
    public int maxScore = 10; // Максимальное количество очков

    private UnityEngine.Object explosion;

    private void Start()
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;

        explosion = Resources.Load("explosion");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && IsCursorOverObject(itemToSell))
        {
            SellObject();
        }
    }

    private bool IsCursorOverObject(GameObject obj)
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            return hit.transform.gameObject == obj;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void SellObject()
    {
        GameObject explosionRef = (GameObject)Instantiate(explosion);
        explosionRef.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

        Destroy(itemToSell);
        score = Mathf.Min(score + scoreValue, maxScore);
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }
}

i tried using chatgpt but it made things even worse and broke the whole code/ p.s max score not working

Where is scoreText coming from? Does every item has it's own reference to the object? This makes the score variable be local for every object, so of course setting the text to TMP will overwrite the score. If you want to have the score tracked for every item you can sell, you have to either store the score somewhere else (like a "Manager"-class) or make it static.

Not sure if you are modifying the value within the editor but, your maxScore = 10, so whenever you SellObject() the Mathf.Min will always choose maxScore due to score + scoreValue > maxScore.
Not sure if there is anything else occurring due to the amount of code provided.
